# How do you reflect on the current sytax scope of the cursor?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to create a bit of functionality that will only occur when the cursor is within a double quoted string in a ruby file.

How can I check if the cursor is within a given syntax like that?

Answer (score 3):

This will return the current syntax group.

```
function! SyntaxItem()
  return synIDattr(synID(line("."),col("."),1),"name")
endfunction
```

From: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Showing_syntax_highlight_group_in_statusline
Also See: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Identify_the_syntax_highlighting_group_used_at_the_cursor

Comment: I didn't find a satisfactory answer to my question on the site, but I eventually googled up the right thing so I figured I would just post the answer here for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is built on top of the functions snippet Andy gave you. After that, we can build more advanced functions and commands.

That's what I've done with my [map-tools plugin](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhBrackets#The_VimL_library). Here are various examples of use:

- [for C](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/cpp/trunk/ftplugin/c/c_snippets.vim)
- [for C++](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/cpp/trunk/ftplugin/cpp/cpp_snippets.vim)
- [for VimL](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/misc/trunk/ftplugin/vim_set.vim)
- [for shell scripts](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/misc/trunk/ftplugin/sh_set.vim)

HTH.